# radio Button Report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have created quite a lot of radio button reports in the past and they work very well. And all the while, the structures in terms of columns have been the same. For example, say A is `true` then, `Tax`, `Bill` and `Date` columns are returned with certain information. And if A is `false`, the same columns are returned but with different meaning. Similar reports I have created using same dataset. Now I am to develop a report were if A is `true`, `Tax`, `Bill` and `Date` columns are returned otherwise (if A is false) `Name` `Address` and `Phone Number` are to be returned. I have written out the Stored Procedure and it works very fine but considering that SSRS Tables are rigid so cannot dynamically set columns to return my values from quires without first designing it structure, how do I go about designing this type of report to work well with my radio button? Do I have to create two dataset? If I do and design the `false` part of the report, how to I get it to run or go to the false part of the report when the radio button is set to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

No need to overcomplicate it - simply use an Expression to manage the Visibility of the parts of the table you don't want showing up.

Dynamic datasets are very difficult to do in SSRS, and require you to either essentially pivot your data with a tablix using column grouping (aka, a matrix), or write your query with fields that will return different values based off parameter input, but that will always be the same number and order of fields - so you end up with a dataset that looks like VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, where each field can mean something totally different depending on the input... which is very difficult to maintain in the long term.